# how to parse the image using NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser, xml-parsing

I need help for parsing the image using dictionary. i can get the text data using dictionary but can't parse the image of the corresponding content using dictionary here my code

```
   -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
            currentElement = [elementName copy];
           if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
                         item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                         ktitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                         kpubdate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                         kitem = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                        //kmedia = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
                         klink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                         kdescription = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                         }
          }
       -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
          if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
                         [item setObject:ktitle forKey:@"title"];
                         [item setObject:klink forKey:@"link"];
                         [item setObject:kdescription forKey:@"description"];
                         [item setObject:kpubdate forKey:@"pubDate"];
                         //kmedia = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage           keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:@"media:content"]];
                         //[item setObject:kmedia forKey:@"media:content"];
                         [arrayList addObject:[item copy]];
                         }
          }
      -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
                if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]){
                          [ktitle appendString:string];
                 }
                 else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
                           [klink appendString:string];
                 }
                 else if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]){
                           [kdescription appendString:string];
                 }
       }
```

Comment: This question is too vague. We're not here to read and write your code for you, rather please phrase specific, concise problems.

Comment: @Marcel- i thought that if i add code you can easily understand my problem thats y i add my part of the code.

Comment: Fair enough, I see. The problem is just that it's not very clear what this code is all about. What kind of image? An UIImage/NSImage? Or some kind of file system image? And how would you go about "parsing" an image, whatever it is? What kind of xml are you parsing? What's "corresponding content"? I think that's the problem here. Add some context information and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: @marcel- i like to parse the UIImage it is NSXMLParsing and the link is http://www.brownbears.com/landing/headlines-featured?feed=rss_2.0

Answer (score 0):

finally i found answer small mistake is I parse the tag instead of url

Thanks for the help